# @ModelAttribute Object Fields Not Returned to Controller

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I have a pretty simple controller that 1) loads an object to be used by a form (view) and 2) accepts changes to that object submitted via that form. The controller ("PersonController") looks like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/accountsettings/{personid}")
public String loadAccountSettings(@PathVariable("personid") int personid,
                              ModelMap model){
    Person person = personService.find(personid);
    model.addAttribute("person",person);
    return "account-settings-form";
}

@RequestMapping(value="/saveaccountsettings")
public String saveSettings(@ModelAttribute("person") Person person){
    personService.update(person);
    return "account-settings-form";
}
```

The "Person" pojo looks like this:

```
public class Person {

    private id int;
    private String name;
    private String username;
    private String phoneNumber;

    //getters and setters follow   

}
```

And my form (account-settings-form.jsp) has the following:

```
<form:form commandName="person" action="/saveaccountsettings">
   <form:input path="name" /><br />
   <form:input path="username" /><br />
   <form:input path="phoneNumber" /><br />
   <input type="submit" />
</form:form>
```

The problem I'm having is that, when the form loads the data (loadAccountSettings), all fields are populated as expected (name, username and phone number). When I go to process the update, however, the phone number field is seen as null, even though data is in the form and (upon inspection using Firebug), I see the value being passed back as a parameter.

Does anyone know why the controller would be missing this field's (person.phoneNumber) value?

Thanks in advance.

-e

Comment: Can you show your code of Person class with its getter and setters?

Comment: I agree with @JapanTrivedi, that seems to be a problem with the setter of phoneNumber. And another thing: you may want to use "modelAttribute" instead of "commandName", according to [this](http://chompingatbits.com/2009/08/25/spring-formtag-commandname-vs-modelattribute/)

Comment: @Dani Yes you are right there is a problem there with **commandName** in form tag. I didn't catch that. :)

eugene please try changing the **commandName** to **modelAttribute** in your form tag because in the controller you have specified as **@ModelAttribute**

Comment: thanks for the additional suggestions. I'll the commandName references in the form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem, a part of the Controller that I left out in the description above and forgot that I added several months ago - an InitBinder method. The phone number field was added recently, but wasn't added to the @InitBinder's array of allowedFields:

```
@InitBinder
public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder){
    binder.setAllowedFields(new String[]{
        "name", "username", "phoneNumber"
    });
}
```